# Class instance must be visible in more classes OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

how can I do for making a class instance visible in more classes using OSGi framework?  I explain better:  when I call `start()` method of Activator.java the program instance a class(`PoolThreadClass`). If I want make visibile `PoolThreadClass` to other class that are in the same bundle how can I do? I was thinking to make a static class that save the class' handle but I don't know if it's correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Within the same bundle, you can use any way you'ld have done in a non-OSGI environment.
You only have to take care of particular things when you're dealing with other bundles.

The particularity of OSGI resides in the way to communicate between bundles. You must export your classes to make them visible, and should consider using exported interfaces and publish services implementations.

However, each bundle is like a self-contained standard java application with all it's standard rules. Class and instances scope and visibility apply as usual.

Comment: So I can use a static class for save the handle or not? BEcause I don't how to share the handle with other classes. All the classes must use the same handle class

Comment: You can implements a Singleton pattern (by making a public static final instance in a class, for example). Your class doesn't have to be static (wouldn't make sense anyway), only your instance sould be.